# PATH variable for anaconda in Fedora

Tags: path, bashrc, datascience-anaconda

After installing Anaconda in /opt/anaconda3 i modified ~/.bashrc for my user by adding PATH variable

```
# .bashrc

# Source global definitions
if [ -f /etc/bashrc ]; then
        . /etc/bashrc
fi

# Uncomment the following line if you don't like systemctl's auto-paging feature:
# export SYSTEMD_PAGER=

# User specific aliases and functions
export PATH="/opt/anaconda3/bin:$PATH"
```

But when I open terminal and type

```
conda list
```

I get

```
bash: conda: command not found
```

What could be the problem?

Comment: Is the `conda` executable in `/opt/anaconda3/bin`?

Comment: Thank you for the clue, in fact there is only plain file named 'conda', after cd to the location and typing 'conda' I get the same output. The problem is Continuum documentation says that PATH should point to this catalogue. https://docs.continuum.io/anaconda/install

Comment: Is the file executable? If it's a script, does it have a valid `#!`-line?

Comment: Thank you for the answers, as it turned out, I just had to restart the terminal. I thought bashrc is reloaded instantly after modyfing, and restart is not necessary. Bests

Comment: No, it is only parsed once when the shell is initialized.

Comment: @JJoao, thanks for your advice, I'm sure it will come in handy

Answer (score -1, accepted):

So as it turned out, I just had to restart terminal, or type `source ~/.bashrc`.